# $\nabla g(x) = (x^{T} x)^{m+1}$ derivation rule

Tags: partial-derivative

I think my calculations of  $\nabla g(x) = (x^{T} x)^{m+1}$ are wrong...mostly the last part. Can someone help me?

Given $g(x) = (x^{T} x)^{m+1}$ we say that $f(x) = x^{T}x = \langle x,x \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}$ thus:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \nabla f(x) = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    {{\partial}\over{\partial x_{1}}}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})\\
    {{\partial}\over{\partial x_{2}}}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})\\
    \vdots\\
    {{\partial}\over{\partial x_{n}}}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})
    \end{pmatrix}
    = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2x_{1}\\
    2x_{2}\\
    \vdots\\
    2x_{n}\\
    \end{pmatrix}
    = 2x
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
now, we can derive
\begin{equation}
    \nabla g(x) = (m+1)(x^{T}x)^{m}2x
\end{equation}

Comment: Its correct, you went from something "like $x^{2m+2}$" to something "like $(2m+2)x^{2m+1}"$, in perfect analogy with the dimension 1 case

Comment: You have the correct result. Use the chain rule with $h:y\mapsto y^{m+1}$, $f:x\mapsto x^Tx$ and $g=h\circ f$.